# What do you gain from upgrading NHibernate 1.2?

Tags: nhibernate, upgrade

I have one project using NHibernate 1.2. I know it's old, but I've used it since I'm working off NHibernate in Action, which targets that same version.

I've been thinking I should update my understanding of the tool, as well as the tool itself. But I wonder what the differences are between versions. I know 2.1 has been current for some time, and that 3.0 is in the works.

What benefits or features are gained, lost, or changed when moving to NHibernate 2.1 or 3.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Off the top of my head and mixing 2.X and 3.0 features... LINQ support, EventListeners (more powerful Interceptors), System.Transaction support, generics support, multiquery, future queries, SchemaUpdate (rather than just SchemaExport), much better HQL parser, ... Plus numerous bug fixes. A lot has been going on in the NHibernate world since NH 1.2...

Comment: I agree. First-class LINQ support in NH3 (via the ISession.Query<T>() extension method) is much improved over Ayende's proof-of-concept for NH2.X. The new ISession.QueryOver<T>() strongly-typed Criteria support is also nice.

Answer (score 7):

With the 3.0.0 release, NHibernate
 includes support for LINQ, along with
 additional features such as:

Along with a long list of bug fixes
 and improvements, it has several new
 features including

- A new strongly
  typed criteria API called [**QueryOver**](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)
- [**Lazy loading of columns**](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx)
- Alias delimiting in generated SQL
- Support for DetachedCriteria within
  IStatelessSession.
- Improved support for `LINQ`, overcoming the `HQL` limitations of the previous provider.

Breaking change:

- Upgrading users should be aware that
  one of the fixes means that null
  values in dictionaries are no longer
  silently ignored, which has the
  potential to break existing
  application code.

Answer (score 3):

James Kovacs summarized it pretty well, but for a complete list of changes check https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/releasenotes.txt

It contains every single bug/improvement/new feature for all NH releases.

Answer (score 1):

You get Linq support!

Answer (score 0):

I started on 2.x+ so I can't say much...but I'll for sure upgrade to 3.0 once it's out of beta. Mainly because `QueryOver` looks like ICriteria on type safe steriods!

Answer (score 0):

v3: Removal of the dependency on log4Net (which is often a love-it or hate-it thing)