# NHibernate 3: is it worth migrating?

Tags: migration, nhibernate-3

We are using Nhibernate 1.2 on a big .NET 3.5 C# project and we are considering upgrading to Nhibernate 3.1. But I'm a little puzzled as I don't find over the Internet much articles dealing with

- improvements of the new versions (2.0 -> 3.1)
- benchmarks between 1.2, 2.x, 3.x

Most of the time people are just saying: NHibernate X.Y is out, it's great, it's wonderful, you have to upgrade, and linking to the ChangeLog.

By far I just have heard of Linq2Nhibernate & MultiCriteria, nothing on performance benchmarks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you gain from upgrading NHibernate 1.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150387/what-do-you-gain-from-upgrading-nhibernate-1-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't encounter any issue and do not need to upgrade your application, the "if it's not broken, do not fix it" rule applies.

Otherwise : [What do you gain from upgrading NHibernate 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150387/what-do-you-gain-from-upgrading-nhibernate-1-2)